# Can I send myself an IM with Microsoft Lync?

Tags: instant-messaging, lync

When I am logged into Microsoft Lync on two different computers, is there any way to send myself an IM?

Typical use case is simply to send myself links to websites that I wish to open on a different computer. *(Sure, links can be sent via email to myself, saved to a text file on a shared drive, etc. IM just involves less clicking around.)*

There are other ways IM-ing yourself could be useful:

- quick reminders you just want to keep up on different machines for a few minutes
- making your secondary computer beep on cue
- having a little formatting sandbox, before you send stuff to co-workers, double-checking to make sure Lync does not translate URLs with funny characters *(colon, port number, etc.)* into smilie faces, special characters, etc.

I can find nothing in the Microsoft documentation or Lync FAQ pages on this topic.